# Dynamic p tag depends on dropdown select - Javascript Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I guess its simple for javascipt masters . Basically I want to change price(which is default by large) when i select the small size pizza .. Ive tried something but nothing happened

Here is **HTML**

```
<div class="row  portfolio-containerr">
        @foreach($product as $p)
        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center portfolio-item {{$p->category_id}} ">
            <div class="card bg-transparent  " style="width: 14rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('front/')}}/assets/img/1.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{$p->title}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-center">{{$p->description}}</p>
          <p product-id="" style="color:#ff4a17;font-size: 20px ">{{$p->price}}</p>


          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Large</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a product-id="{{$p->id}}"class="dropdown-item size-click" href="#">Large</a>          
              <a product-id="{{$p->id}}"class="dropdown-item size-click" href="#">Small</a>          
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function getData(Request $request){
    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->id);
    return response()->json($product);
}
```

**javascript**

```
 $(function(){

  $('.portfolio-item').on('click', '.size-click', function(){
    id = $(this)[0].getAttribute('product-id');

    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'{{url("/getData")}}',
      data:{id:id},
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
          $('p')[0].getAttribute("product-id", data.id);
          $('p[product-id="data.id"]').text(data.priceS);
          
        
        
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit more. You want to change the price in database or in the view? How do you get the large and small price?

Comment: Do you want to display the large price by default in <p> tag and when the user selects small size from dropdown, you make an ajax request to get the small price and then replace it instead of the large price in the <p> tag?

Comment: Exactly , i wanna change p tag which shows price

Comment: In your ajax respnose, you don't seem to return any price but the same product that you already have displayed. Do you have both small and large prices in the product object like $p->large_price and $p->small_price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code has several issues which I'll try to address one by one.

**PHP/HTML**

In your HTML (generated by PHP), you are using a non-existent attribute `product-id` to attach an ID to several elements. Instead of "inventing" your own attributes, you should use a `data-` attribute here, because that's what they are made for. For example, instead of

```
<a product-id="..." class="..." href="#"> ... </a>
```

you should use

```
<a data-product-id="..." class="..." href="#"> ... </a>
```

This goes for all elements that currently have a `product-id` attribute.

---

*Fixed PHP/HTML*

Using `data-` attributes.

Note: Both `<a>`-elements receive *the same* product ID, regardless of the product's size – is that correct?

```
<div class="row  portfolio-containerr">
  @foreach($product as $p)
  <div class="col-lg-3 text-center portfolio-item {{$p->category_id}} ">
    <div class="card bg-transparent  " style="width: 14rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('front/')}}/assets/img/1.png" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{$p->title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-center">{{$p->description}}</p>
        <p data-product-id="" style="color:#ff4a17;font-size: 20px ">{{$p->price}}</p>

        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Large</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
          </button>
        
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a data-product-id="{{$p->id}}" class="dropdown-item size-click" href="#">Large</a>          
            <a data-product-id="{{$p->id}}" class="dropdown-item size-click" href="#">Small</a>          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

The JavaScript (as it seems) has the following errors/issues that should be fixed:

*Implicit global variables*

As it stands, you try to grab the product ID from the clicked element and store it in a variable `id` (line 4). However, it looks as if that variable is an implicit global variable (hence it will be attached to the `window` object). You should use `var id = ...` instead of `id = ...`.

*Too much complexity*

The same line has too much complexity. Why do you wrap the current element that has been clicked (`this`) into a jQuery collection if you *immediately* unwrap it (via `[0]`)? Just write `this.getAttribute( ... )` and you're done, no need for `$(this)[0].getAttribute( ... )`.

Oh, and if you follow my suggestion and use `data-` attributes, don't use `getAttribute` – use `this.dataset.productId` to get the ID and `this.dataset.productId = ...` to set it.

*Invalid URL and/or useless interpolation*

On line 8, you are passing an invalid URL to `$.ajax( ... )`. It seems you want to generate the correct URL with the help of a `url( ... )` function and use string interpolation to pass the URL to the call to `$.ajax`. However, the `url( ... )` function seems to already return a string that contains the URL. Therefor, it's unlikely that you need string interpolation at all. If I'm right, just use `url: url('/getData'),` and you are fine.

*Useless call to `getAttribute`*

The code in line 12 (success callback) makes a useless call to `getAttribute`. It's useless because the value returned by `getAttribute` isn't used anywhere. Also, `getAttribute` takes a single parameter, not two parameters. Did you mean `setAttribute` instead? If not, you can safely delete line 12. Otherwise, use `setAttribute`.

I'm not really sure that the code works correct, even if you use `setAttribute`. Let me explain: Calling `$('p')[0]` will give you the first paragraph/`<p>`-element *of the whole page* – probably not what you want. Instead, you want the first paragraph inside the corresponding `.portfolio-item` element. To do that, you have to pass a *second* argument to `$( ... )` that marks the root element. Just save a reference to the `.portfolio-item` inside the click handler (but outside of the `success` callback) in a variable that you can then use later.

*Wrong selector*

Finally, in line 13 you pass the selector `'p[product-id="data.id"]'` to the `$( ... )` function. It seems you want to select the `<p>` element that has the product ID returned by the call to `$.ajax`. In that case, you have to generate a selector that contains the actual ID. Something like this:

```
`$('p[product-id="' + data.id + '"]')`
```

Although it seems you don't need any of this if you save the `<p>`-element you manipulated in line 12 into a variable. That's because the mentioned selector queries the DOM for exactly the same `<p>`-element. This means you can use the "native" `.textContent` property instead of jQuery's `.text` function.

---

*Fixed JavaScript (with data-attributes)*

Here is the complete JS code with most of the above mentioned issues gone.

```
$(function(){

  $('.portfolio-item').on('click', '.size-click', function(){
    var id = this.dataset.productId,                // <-- uses data-attributes now
        pitem = $(this).closest('.portfolio-item'); // <-- reference to containing portfolio-item element
        
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url('/getData'),                         // <-- fixed URL
      data: { id: id },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var p = $('p', pitem)[0];                   // <-- get first paragraph in parent

        p.dataset.productId = data.id;              // <-- assign product id to data-attribute
        p.textContent = data.priceS;                // <-- display the price
      }
    })
  })

});
```